# Spring Cloud Config - Cannot clone or checkout repository: ssh://git@github.com/<user>/repo.git

Tags: spring-cloud-config

When I try the URL with `https` it works but I don't want to have the username and password. I am able to perform a git clone with the above url and its working. But when I try it in the code and hit the localhost:8888/default endpoint I get the error:

```
{
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "Cannot clone or checkout repository: ssh://git@github.com/<user>/config-repo.git",
"path": "/licensingservice/default",
"status": 404,
"timestamp": "2018-04-30T23:32:54.726+0000"
}
```

Here is my application.yml entry

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://git@github.com/<user>/config-repo.git
          searchPaths: licensingservice
```

I am using spring cloud config - Finchley.Not. No sure what I am missing. Please suggest.

Comment: Just make sure you're using '//' like the following: spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=E:\\config-repo

Answer (score 0):

Few things to inspect:

1. Do you have github in your known_hosts? If not, then it will prompt you to enter password even you have key pairs that might cause the error.
2. Do you have SSH keys under /home/{you}/.ssh/ folder?
3. When you generate your keys, did you use passphrase? If so, you need to include the `passphrase` key in your YAML file.

If all above are okay. Then download the spring-cloud-config-server, debug the `org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.class`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your machine's ssh key to the repo.

Ssh key should be generate with the following command: 
**ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"**

For more info, you can check this link

https://skryvets.com/blog/2019/05/27/solved-issue-spring-cloud-config-server-private-ssh-key/

Answer (score -1):

I also faced a similar problem with spring cloud config server. You need to add an additional property `spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true` in application.properties file.